# ArrayOutOfIndex... Parsing URL's but dont know exact index for each HTML page?

Tags: java, android

I am parsing some URL links with the following..

```
  Document jsDoc2 = null;
          try {
              jsDoc2 = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                  Elements thumbs = jsDoc2.select("div.latest-media-images img.latestMediaThumb");
                  List<String> thumbLinks = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                  for(Element thumb : thumbs) {
                      thumbLinks.add(thumb.attr("src"));
                  }
                  for(String thumb : thumbLinks) {
                     url0 = thumbLinks.get(0);
                     url1 = thumbLinks.get(1); 
                     url2 = thumbLinks.get(2);

                     Log.e("URL0", url0);
                     Log.e("URL1", url1);
                     Log.e("URL2", url2);
```

After testing the code with multiple sources. ive ran across a problem.

```
09-19 20:59:56.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7793): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
09-19 20:59:56.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7793):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
09-19 20:59:56.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7793):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
```

Sometimes there arent three links availible and of cource when i ask to get the index of 2 and it doesnt exist it FC's.

How can i code defensively or create a better way to implement this. The uncertainty of not knowing the exact amount of urls it will parse and load into the list

EDIT:

My COde now

```
 for(int i = 0; i< thumbLinks.size(); i++) {
                            Log.e("URL" + i, thumbLinks.get(i));




                     url0 = thumbLinks.get(i);
                     url1 = thumbLinks.get(i); 

                     //Fix index out of bounds exception
                     url2 = thumbLinks.get(i);



                  }
```

Comment: This makes no sense: you've got a for-each loop, and you're not using it but instead are trying to hard-code your way through the collection, and inside the loop no less. Why?

Comment: This suggests that you may benefit by going through an introductory Java tutorial or two before trying to tackle Android programming. It's not time wasted, believe me.

Comment: Well could you show me a better way?

Comment: And ive taken 2 years of java in HS..Ive just graduated from hs in june.FYI

Comment: That's what a for list does for you. Review for lists, foreach lists and arraylists. Shoot Russell shows you how to do this with a for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. Ive see where i made a beginners mistake. Again im new to this. Only two years of HS experience...

Comment: that means that you have two more years of classroom training in Java than I've ever had. I've only had one semester of computer language training in Pascal, that's it.

Comment: Wow dude bad ass..Good story. So what do you do for work?

Comment: taught myself as you're doing now. keep at it.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words. So how do you make use of your new skills?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3603/discussion-between-coder-for-life22-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this might work better for your loop structure

```
for(int i = 0; i< thumbLinks.size(); i++) {
    Log.e("URL" + i, thumbLinks.get(i));
}
```

You could also just shorten this to something like:

```
Elements thumbs = jsDoc2.select("div.latest-media-images img.latestMediaThumb");

int index = 0;

for(Element thumb : thumbs) {
    Log.e("URL" + index, (thumb.attr("src"));
    index++;
}
```

This second option reduces the operational time by reducing the looping structures and providing the same result. You will not get index out of bound errors with either of these because it will only add URLs if there are thumbs in your list.

The reason your code is failing is because you're explicitly trying to call indexes and essentially ignoring the loop structure all together. The reason to use a loop is so you don't have explicitly get objects from the array and chance out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: So how do i call my ArrayList.get method, based on this? if i call it to get 3 strings from the array list but there are only 2. How will my code know not to look for that 3rd string?

Comment: He's showing you how to use get. And the for list has a maximum, here set at the size() of the array list. Again, this is all spelled out in the basic tutorials.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking here. With the looping structure I've provided it will only put as many URLs in the Log as there are elements in the thumbLinks. If there are only 2 elements in your ArrayList, this looping structure will output the equivalent of Log.e(Log0, url0) and Log.e(Log1, url1).

Comment: Updated my answer for further clarification

Comment: COuld you post the Strings in the code too to show how the index is passed?

Comment: How can i add a string for each time it finds a url? Lets say if it only finds 1//how would the code look?

Comment: The code supplied will provide the String you're looking for. In the example, the "URL" + i portion will generate a String based on  the current value of int i. On the first iteration of the loop, i = 0 so the output will be equivalent to Log.e("URL0", thumbLinks.get(0)), on the next loop it will be equivalent to Log.e("URL1", thumbLinks.get(1)) and so on. You need to learn to read past the literal construct of the code and think about how it will process, write each iteration down on a piece of paper so you can visualize the flow.